# Swift 4 AppDelegate Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2 error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

** i have gone through similar questions but havent been able to solve the problem..the error only occurs when i add any label or imageview but works fine when i change background color

any help will be greatly appreciated(stuck on this since evening). Thanks in advance!

hey guys I'm trying to build a simple ios project(fairly new to swift) and whenever i try to run my code in simulator i always get an error shown in the picture below. All i have done in this project so far is add a label and change background but when i run the code it shows succeeded but fails to run in any simulator and points me to the appdelegate.swift file [Appdelegate Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxQc6.png)

This is my code:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

viewcontroller.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

In my main.storyboard i have just added a label and changed background color

Comment: See what is error in debug section

Comment: you can see the error over here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxQc6.png  it just print outs 105553117635304

Comment: remove breakpoint and see if app crashes or gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assumed this was an error but it's actually a debugging breakpoint. You inadvertently set a breakpoint which is easy to do. Where the line is green, it says breakpoint but does not say error.

To remove any breakpoints, click on the blue arrow seen in your screenshot. With the breakpoints removed, the code should run normally.

Answer (score 0):

well, that just a `debugging breakpoint` is shown in the image If you have added `breakpoints` that is completely fine.

1. Either remove all breakpoints and try to run the program and check if it still stops there.
2. if you added an `exceptional breakpoint` then do this shown in the image below

[image]